# Multiple 'roles' in a model field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I am trying to setup a model where a user can post an advertisement and along with other information such as the ad content, they will be allowed to use checkboxes in the form to select a few options/categories of what their advertisement is looking for.

For example,
"Looking for washer and dryer" then they can click the checkboxes for 'Appliances, Home` and maybe some other that they feel their ad applies to.

The problem is, I haven't even setup my model yet. What is the best way to have my model hold the categories that the user picks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This video is exactly what you're looking for.](http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes)

Have a HABTM relationship.

So you have a table called Ads, and a table called Categories. Make a table called AdCategories, where each record has only two fields: an ad_id and a category_id. So each record links an ad to a category.

More info on HABTM can be found [here.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association)

Comment: He did a revised video for that, and in it I believe he uses has_many relationships. Would this be a better choice than HABTM?

Comment: @user1076802 Nope. Think about it logically rather than programmatically: ads have potentially many categories, and categories have potentially many ads. If you just say "ads have many categories", then each category must have a field that specifies the ad to which it belongs. But obviously each category has many ads that fall under its description. Also, you'll be able to do things like display all ads which fall under a certain category by doing a HABTM relationship.